# How can I overlay PNGs with transparency over a video? (each PNG should cover one frame)

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video (original.mp4), and then I have a series of PNGs with transparency that I want to overlay every frame in the video.

The strategy I'm using is:

1. Create a video from the PNGs

   ffmpeg -framerate 60 -pattern_type glob -i images/*.png -c:v libx264 out.mp4
2. Normalize the two videos to have the same dimensions

   ffmpeg -i out.mp4 -vf scale=1920:960,setsar=0:1,setdar=16:9 out2.mp4
   ffmpeg -i original.mp4 -vf scale=1920:960,setsar=0:1,setdar=16:9 original2.mp4
3. Overlay the PNGs video and give it opacity

   ffmpeg -i original2.mp4 -i heatmap2.avi -filter_complex "blend=all_mode='overlay':all_opacity=0.7" result.mp4

This almost works, but the video created from the PNGs has a black background.  I've also tried encoding the video as .mov and .avi, which are supposed to retain transparency.  However when I did that, the black background still came back after overlaying it.

How can I seamlessly overlay the PNGs (each is a single frame of the video) as a video with transparency over the original?

[Edit 2] From Mulvya's suggestion, here is the command I tried

```
ffmpeg -i original.mp4 -framerate 60 -pattern_type glob -i "images/*.png" -filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref=iw:ih[ovr]; [ovr][0:v]blend=all_mode='overlay':all_opacity=0.7[v]" -map [v] result.mp4
```

And the output:

```
ffmpeg version 2.8.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/2.8.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-opencl --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libxvid --enable-vda
  libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
  libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'original.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: mp41mp42isom
    creation_time   : 2016-03-08 18:24:07
  Duration: 00:00:06.91, start: 0.023220, bitrate: 2466 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x960 [SAR 2769:2768 DAR 2769:1384], 2331 kb/s, 29.95 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-03-08 18:24:07
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 102 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2016-03-08 18:24:07
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
Input #1, image2, from 'images/*.png':
  Duration: 00:00:07.10, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1920x960, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 60 tbn, 60 tbc
File 'result.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
[libx264 @ 0x7fa5b2000c00] using SAR=2769/2768
[libx264 @ 0x7fa5b2000c00] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0x7fa5b2000c00] profile High, level 4.2
[libx264 @ 0x7fa5b2000c00] 264 - core 148 r2601 a0cd7d3 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
[libx264 @ 0x7fa5b2001e00] using SAR=2769/2768
[libx264 @ 0x7fa5b2001e00] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 AVX2 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0x7fa5b2001e00] profile High, level 4.2
[libx264 @ 0x7fa5b2001e00] 264 - core 148 r2601 a0cd7d3 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'result.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: mp41mp42isom
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1920x960 [SAR 2769:2768 DAR 2769:1384], q=-1--1, 60 fps, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 libx264
    Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1920x960 [SAR 2769:2768 DAR 2769:1384], q=-1--1, 60 fps, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.60.100 libx264
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> scale2ref:ref
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> blend:bottom
  Stream #1:0 (png) -> scale2ref:default
  scale2ref:ref -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  blend -> Stream #0:1 (libx264)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[image2 @ 0x7fa5b1807000] Thread message queue blocking; consider raising the thread_queue_size option (current value: 8)
frame=  419 fps= 31 q=-1.0 Lq=-1.0 size=    4995kB time=00:00:07.06 bitrate=5790.8kbits/s dup=210 drop=0
video:4981kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.291158%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa5b2000c00] frame I:2     Avg QP:21.72  size:142050
[libx264 @ 0x7fa5b2000c00] frame P:118   Avg QP:23.59  size: 15323
[libx264 @ 0x7fa5b2000c00] frame B:299   Avg QP:25.88  size:  1203
[libx264 @ 0x7fa5b2000c00] consecutive B-frames:  4.8%  0.0%  0.7% 94.5%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa5b2000c00] mb I  I16..4: 13.2% 60.6% 26.1%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa5b2000c00] mb P  I16..4:  0.7%  0.9%  0.2%  P16..4: 29.9%  7.9%  4.7%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:55.6%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa5b2000c00] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8: 16.0%  0.3%  0.1%  direct: 0.1%  skip:83.4%  L0:35.5% L1:63.0% BI: 1.5%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa5b2000c00] 8x8 transform intra:55.6% inter:68.7%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa5b2000c00] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 50.1% 59.2% 20.9% inter: 3.3% 2.8% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa5b2000c00] i16 v,h,dc,p: 11% 47%  9% 33%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa5b2000c00] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 15% 27% 20%  4%  6%  6%  9%  4%  9%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa5b2000c00] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 18% 25%  9%  6%  8%  7% 11%  6%  9%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa5b2000c00] i8c dc,h,v,p: 50% 29% 15%  6%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa5b2000c00] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa5b2000c00] ref P L0: 65.4% 15.1% 13.9%  5.5%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa5b2000c00] ref B L0: 88.0%  8.6%  3.4%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa5b2000c00] ref B L1: 96.4%  3.6%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa5b2000c00] kb/s:2808.83
[libx264 @ 0x7fa5b2001e00] frame I:2     Avg QP:15.35  size: 38416
[libx264 @ 0x7fa5b2001e00] frame P:108   Avg QP:20.76  size: 13229
[libx264 @ 0x7fa5b2001e00] frame B:316   Avg QP:25.94  size:  3612
[libx264 @ 0x7fa5b2001e00] consecutive B-frames:  0.9%  0.0%  1.4% 97.7%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa5b2001e00] mb I  I16..4: 33.8% 57.9%  8.2%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa5b2001e00] mb P  I16..4:  1.0%  4.2%  0.8%  P16..4: 19.9%  3.8%  2.7%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:67.6%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa5b2001e00] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.2%  0.1%  B16..8: 11.4%  1.3%  0.3%  direct: 0.9%  skip:85.8%  L0:52.0% L1:42.9% BI: 5.1%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa5b2001e00] 8x8 transform intra:67.0% inter:77.7%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa5b2001e00] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 38.2% 68.3% 42.4% inter: 2.3% 6.1% 1.9%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa5b2001e00] i16 v,h,dc,p: 51% 32%  8%  9%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa5b2001e00] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 19% 16% 35%  4%  5%  5%  6%  4%  6%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa5b2001e00] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 25% 21% 15%  6%  7%  7%  8%  5%  5%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa5b2001e00] i8c dc,h,v,p: 42% 25% 16% 17%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa5b2001e00] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa5b2001e00] ref P L0: 71.2%  5.7% 14.7%  8.3%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa5b2001e00] ref B L0: 90.2%  7.9%  2.0%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa5b2001e00] ref B L1: 96.8%  3.2%
[libx264 @ 0x7fa5b2001e00] kb/s:2982.61
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

H.264, which is what `libx264` encodes to, does not support transparency. Neither does `mpeg4`, the default codec for AVI. MOV output defaults to `libx264` as well.

You can do this in one command:

```
ffmpeg -i original.mp4 -framerate 60 -pattern_type glob -i images/*.png \
-filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1920x960,setdar=16:9[base];[1:v]scale=1920x960,setdar=16:9[ovr];\
 [ovr][base]blend=all_mode='overlay':all_opacity=0.7[v]"
-map [v] result.mp4
```

You don't need to scale both videos.If you just want the PNGs to scale the same as the base video, you can use `scale2ref`:

```
ffmpeg -i original.mp4 -framerate 60 -pattern_type glob -i images/*.png \
-filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref=iw:ih[ovr][base]; \
 [ovr][base]blend=all_mode='overlay':all_opacity=0.7[v]"
-map [v] result.mp4
```

Now, you have specified a custom DAR (`1920x960` is not `16:9`). If that needs to be set, use

```
[1:v][0:v]scale2ref=iw:ih,setdar=16:9[ovr][base];
```

---

This uses a different method to apply the overlay.

```
ffmpeg -i original.mp4 -framerate 60 -pattern_type glob -i "images/*.png" \
-filter_complex "[1:v][0:v]scale2ref=iw:ih[ovr][base]; \
 [ovr]colorchannelmixer=aa=0.7[ovrl]; [base][ovrl]overlay[v]"
-map [v] result.mp4
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response.  I tried your first solution as well as scale2ref and they both gave me errors: [AVFilterGraph @ 0x7fd95155c140] Error initializing threading.
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x7fd95155c140] Error creating filter 'null'
Error opening filters!

Comment: Also, when trying your suggestions, ffmpeg asks if I want to overwrite the images files (each one).  Why is that?  They aren't changing, are they?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25559917/5726027) for the error message. For the overwrite issue, can you post the command and its console output?

Comment: I posted the command and console output.  For overwrite, I just added -y to ignore the messages.

Comment: Did you check the process thread limit for ffmpeg? Post the console output without `-y`. You shouldn't be getting that message.

Comment: And I notice that your video is 30 fps, so every other PNG frame will be dropped during overlay. Is 60 the correct framerate for the images?

Comment: Yes 60 is the correct framerate for the images...although I could create the images so they are 30fps. The console output I posted above was with `-y`, which is why I am confused...

Comment: Okay I misread your comment - I re-ran the command without `-y` and posted the output.

Comment: You're on OS X? I don't know if the `/` needs to be escaped. Try `images\/*.png`. Because the ffmpeg command isn't set to alter the images.

Comment: Ah yeah, I tried it with "images/*.png" and that worked.  The result was just the original video without the PNGs overlayed though.  I updated my post and pasted the full output

Comment: Corrected the scale2ref filter

Comment: Ah okay! That created the video with the PNGs overlayed.  However, the result is still turning out darker than it should be- the PNGs seem to retain the black background for the transparency...

Comment: That's because I carried over your blend method, which applies transparency to all channels. Editing command for a new approach,

Comment: Ah yeah - you can assume that is wrong because I got that from somewhere else :).  Basically I just have an original video, and pngs with transparent backgrounds.  I want to seamlessly overlay the PNGs and possibly introduce more opacity (so you can see through the images to the video)

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much for all your help.  The last one worked perfectly.

Comment: hey sorry to surface this again, but how would I copy the audio from the original video over to the output?

Comment: Insert `-map 0:a -c:a copy` before output name.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to add dynamic image overlay on live stream video input? Means we can keep changing image overlay after video stream started?

Comment: @AnkitMaheshwari although a bit off topic, and also I'm 4 years late, but the way I'd do that is to use Chrome to generate the overlay and use OBS Studio to combine the video and the overlay. Haven't done it for a while but it handled transparency from Chrome no problem.